# Dynamically imported component is treated as JSX element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with dynamic import in React.

Here's the code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [Component, setComponent] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    import("./Div").then(imp => {
      console.log(typeof imp.default); // function
      setComponent(imp.default);
    });
  }, []);

  if (!Component) return null;

  console.log(typeof Component); // object

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Component />
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

React fails with the following error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `App`.
```

I am not quite sure what it means. When I check the type of `imp.default` it correctly shows that it is a function. But when I render it, it seems to think that `Component` is an object, not a component. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-bogdan-mmmru?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I was unknowingly trying to render the **return** value of `Component`, which is why `typeof Component` is `object` in the example above. What this means is you are not allowed to `useState` with functions in the first place. `Component` is a function. It seems like React executes a function internally and only then stores its return value. If, in the example above, I save state as an object like `{ comp: Component }` where `Component` is the imported component and then access it like this:

```js
const { comp: Component } = state;
```

then everything works as intended.

Comment: or `setComponent(() => imp.default)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`React.lazy` to dynamically import components](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy).

Also, there are few mistakes in this snippet:

1. Although `null` is a valid `React.element` you can't render it like `<Component/>`:

```
let Component = null;
// Component = Some valid component
{Component && <Component/>}
```

2. Don't save react elements in a state, its an anti-pattern, use HOC or any boolean value to indicate rendering.

Some working example of your attempt:

```
export default function App() {
  const [Component, setComponent] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const Imp = React.lazy(() => import('./Div'));
    setComponent(<Imp />);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading</div>}>{Component}</React.Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit hardcore-bhabha-owg87]

---

Important side notes: This code is just a working example. If you attempting to use dynamic import **that's not the use case for it**, **it is enough to import the component and conditionally render it**.